# Split a string into keys of associative arrays (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Do you have an idea, how can a string be converted to a variable, e.g.

- there is a string -> `$string = 'one|two|three';`
- there is an array -> `$arr = array('one' => array('two' => array('three' => 'WELCOME')));`

I want to use all with explode(); exploded values to access the array `$arr`. I tried this code:

```
$c = explode('|', $string);
$str = 'arr[' . implode('][', $c) . ']';

echo $$str;
```

It doesnt work, sadly :(  Any ideas?

Comment: I forgot to say, the number of keys isn't static

Comment: no, i don't want to insert any values, i want to read them. The array exists already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sort of recursive function:

```
$ex_keys = array('one', 'two', 'three');
$ex_arr = array('one' => array('two' => array('three' => 'WELCOME')));

function get_recursive_var($keys, $arr) {
    if (sizeof($keys) == 1)
        return $arr[$keys[0]];
    else {
        $key = array_shift($keys);
        return get_recursive_var($keys, $arr[$key]);
    }
}

var_dump(get_recursive_var($ex_keys, $ex_arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong.
You can do what you want with a loop to go through the array level by level

```
$string = 'one|two|three';
$arr = array('one' => array('two' => array('three' => 'WELCOME')));

$c = explode('|', $string);
$result = $arr;

foreach($c as $key)
    $result = $result[$key];

echo $result; // WELCOME
```